# Music bot returning errors at core.py and bot.py

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord

The code for the music bot I'm trying to write in python keeps returning an error with the following code:

```
@bot.command(name='play_song', help='To play song')
async def play(ctx,url):
    
    #if not ctx.message.author.name=="Rohan Krishna" :
    #     await ctx.send('NOT AUTHORISED!')
    #     return
    if 1==1:#try :
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client
        print("try 1 was a success")
        
        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            #voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename)) #ISSUE HERE
            print("try 2 was a success")
            voice = get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
            #voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('test.mp3'), after=your_check)
            #voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
            #voice.source.volume = 0.5
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
    if 1==0:#except:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")
        print("try 3 was unfortunately a success")
```

It normally has a try/except function but I replaced it with if true and false statements to force it to run instead of breaking to determine the exact line of it breaking.  The issue supposedly lies in

```
voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename)) #ISSUE HERE
```

The error I get returned is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "app2.py", line 75, in play
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('test.mp3'), after=your_check)
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 225, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 147, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heyin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

I added the print statements to determine which lines were working so those can obviously be ignored.  It seems to be working fine except for this, other commands in the bot are working appropriately.

Comment: What exactly was unclear to you about the error message?

Comment: I don't understand what the error means.  Is it saying that ffmpeg isn't installed correctly?  If so, how do I fix that?

Comment: download ffmpeg from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html then either add it to path or in the folder of the main file